# disabling text kerning in fabricJs

Tags: svg, fabricjs, kerning

I have fonts with kerning, which is working great with `SVG` and `fabricJs`. but when i am importing `SVG` to `tcpdf` kerning lost. so i want to disable kerning in `fabricJs`. so font will match with pdf output.

Is there any way to do like this?

Comment: This maybe? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning

Comment: issue is when i will embed svg into tcpdf, otherwise its working ok in browser @RobertLongson

Comment: Presumably tcpdf does not support kerning

Comment: @RobertLongson i am assuming to disable kerning in fabricJs. any clue?